# Push files from git to heroku

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have an rails application named as `myapp`. And i have created a git repository recently
and i pushed all my files to git using `git push origin master` this successfully pushed all my files. And later on i created heroku app using `heroku created` on the `myapp` directory.

while checking with `git remote -v` i got following result

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:myappname.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:myappname.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/username/myreponame.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/myreponame.git (push)
```

Now how can i move all my files from git to heroku. Can anyone help.

Comment: I've only used heroku a few times, but I think you're supposed to `git push heroku master` or something like that if you want to deploy to heroku.

Comment: I want to move files only from git to heroku not directly to heroku.

Comment: I don't understand the difference. If you use `git push heroku master`, you should be pushing your code in the `master` branch to heroku.

Answer (score 0):

See the last answer at [Checking in code without deploying on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978199/checking-in-code-without-deploying-on-heroku).

In general, once you `git push heroku master`, it will automatically deploy. So if you don't want that, the easiest would be to push it to a different branch in Heroku.

BUT! Do not treat Heroku like github/bitbucket/insert favourite VCS provider. It just happens to use git as part of its deployment, because that is doing it wrong™.

So you're better of storing your code in github, and let heroku handling deployments (and not store your code).

Comment: Erm, I just explained. Use Heroku _only_ for deployment and hosting, not source control.

Comment: I may be confused merely by your wording. I think that deployment-via-git is one among many ways of "doing it right", and that git-hosting-at-heroku is "doing it wrong." Is this what you mean too?