# Heroku - Git push without building

Tags: git, heroku

I deploy using "git push heroku master", but I'm using 2 buildpacks and it takes some minutes to build everything. My app is still in QA.

So my question is: Is there a way I can update the remote files without going through all this  building process?

Let's say I change

```
<span class="bla">
```

to

```
<span class="foo">
```

I know it won't need to build anything, but I'm forced to build it again.

Comment: "I wish I could test everything locally, but sometimes you just can't" -- why can't you? In most cases, the solution to this issue is to build a proper local testing environment. (The exception is testing things that are specific to controlling the Heroku deployment process.)

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser You're right, the best thing is to test everything locally, and only push when you're done. I removed this part from the question.

Comment: I reposted a similar question in ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/966525/node-js-remote-development-environment-similar-heroku-review-apps

Comment: I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser I can't test locally for example because I am coding in AmpScript which does not have a local environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the Heroku build compiler slug is tied directly into Git.  When you push, a remote [Git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) runs to trigger the rebuild.  (It does this "while you wait," which is why you can press Ctrl-C to cancel the build--and the push.)

Interestingly, [this fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713183) was having the opposite problem--he wanted to rebuild without pushing any changes.  You *can* do that, with an empty commit.  A new commit arriving will trigger the build hook.

At any rate, you can't disable a Git remote's hooks; that's part of the design of Git.  So if you must use Git to publish, the answer to your question is, "no, so have a coffee machine or a webcomic nearby." ;-)

Note that that leaves the possibility of *not* using Git.  I'm totally unfamiliar with it, but <strike>you might look at Heroku's [Anvil](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-anvil)</strike> as a way of releasing without using Git.  Possibly it's what you're looking for.  Let me know if you work something out!

(EDIT: Anvil has been deprecated; apparently [Convox](https://convox.com) is the replacement?  Looks expensive.)

Comment: I was expecting this. But i hoped there was a way like running heroku run bash and then running git pull or something... I held this question for some time, i didn't want to ask it, but building with 2 buildpacks takes longer than the normal building i had before. Thx anyway..

Comment: Interesting suggestion of Anvil. I didn't know that existed. I can't imagine ever needing it in practice, but one never knows.